# Lost in Java generics

Tags: java, generics

What will contain the List listOfFruits ?

```
public class GenericsTest {

static class Fruit {}
static class Apple extends Fruit {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Apple apple = new Apple();
    List<? extends Fruit> listOfFruits = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfFruits.add(apple);
}
```

}

I don't know why when i add apple to the list, it doesn't work , However it fits so well. ( Apple extends Fruit> .

Even if i put another Fruit.

```
Fruit aFruit = new Fruit();
listOfFruits.add(aFruit);
```

Amazing even instance of Fruit doesn't work.

The only way is to remplace 'extends' by 'super'. I really don't understand.

Comment: Understand `PECS`, this will help you figure out when to use `? super` and `? extends` :)

Comment: Also, note that `Producer` and `Consumer` are from the *Collection's* perspective